# Firebase 11.4.2 Proguard Error

Tags: android, firebase, android-proguard

If compile with minifyEnabled false everything is working fine.
But I can't compile with minifyEnabled true with release key

```
Warning:com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader: can't find superclass or interface com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoader

Warning:com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader$Factory: can't find superclass or interface com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoaderFactory
Warning:com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader$FirebaseStorageKey: can't find referenced class com.bumptech.glide.load.Key

Warning:there were 46 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

jk

Comment: also seeing this, found any answer yet?

Comment: @drod Fortunately, yes. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for days, I've found the solution.

Previously, in gradle,  I use

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.1.0'
```

Because I only need ui auth then I change to

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```